# Problem in importing Go Package " example.com/qwert/my_package " in Go 1.20 workspace environment

Tags: go

Respected community member I'm new in Golang, I encounter one scenario.

To the point Question :

**" Is there any relationship between name of module and name of package when we use go workspaces?"**

Detail Explanation :
I have three module in Go workspaces.Folder structure is like shown below:

```
myworkspace-
      -first 
          -first.go
          -go.mod
      -second
          -second.go
          -go.mod
      -third 
          -main.go
          -go.mod
      -go.work
```

Code inside my directory looks like:

first

```
//first.go
package qwerty

func FirstClass() int64 {
    return 1
}

--------------------
-go.mod
--------------------
module firstmod.com/qwerty

go 1.20
```

-second

```
//second.go
package asdfg

func Second() int64 {
    return 2
}


--------------------
-go.mod
--------------------
module secmod.com/asdfg

go 1.20
```

-third

```
//main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "firstmod.com/qwerty"
    "secmod.com/asdfg"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hiii")
    fmt.Println(asdfg.Second())
    fmt.Println(qwerty.FirstClass())
}


--------------------
-go.mod
--------------------
module third.com/zxcvb

go 1.20
```

-go.work

```
go 1.20

use (
    ./first
    ./second
    ./third
)
```

till this point All above code work well.

But
When I create package with diffrent name in file first.go and import it in main.go Its result an error -
Suppose I change name of package from qwerty -> testpackage

Its showing messgae like below-
`"could not import firstmod.com/qwerty/testpackage(no required module provides package "firstmod.com/qwerty/testpackage")"`

I was Expecting package should import but it's not imported.
So again my question **"Is there any relationship between name of module and name of package when we use go workspaces?**"
I'd be thankful if you throw more light on How things are working here.
Thank you.